# Xml bulk insert in oracle table

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, oracle10g, procedures

Im new to oracle, 
what im trying is,
I have an xml, i try to insert the same in a oracle database table, i have formed a query, when i try to insert it. i get some Error like

> Error report -
>   ORA-06550: line 35, column 84:
>   PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   ORA-06550: line 5, column 2:
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

i couldnt able to figure out what i missed, Suggest me how to change the query,

heres my XML and Query which im trying to work.

```html
- <call>
- <callSummary>
  <indId>100</indId> 
  <notificationNo>notification</notificationNo> 
  <orderNo>orderno</orderNo> 
  </callSummary>
- <callList>
- <callDetails>
  <maintenancetype>1</maintenancetype> 
  <serialNo>1</serialNo> 
  <unitType>unit type</unitType> 
  </callDetails>
- <callDetails>
  <maintenancetype>1</maintenancetype> 
  <serialNo>2</serialNo> 
  <unitType>unit type</unitType> 
  </callDetails>
- <callDetails>
  <maintenancetype>2</maintenancetype> 
  <serialNo>1</serialNo> 
  <unitType>unit type</unitType>
  </callDetails>
- <callDetails>
  <maintenancetype>2</maintenancetype> 
  <serialNo>2</serialNo> 
  <unitType>unit type</unitType> 
  </callDetails>
  </callList>
  </call>
```

my Query is

```html
DECLARE  
 call_xml XMLTYPE := xmltype('<call><callSummary><indId>100</indId><notificationNo>notification</notificationNo><orderNo>orderno</orderNo><</callSummary><callList><callDetails><maintenancetype>1</maintenancetype><serialNo>1</serialNo><unitType>unit type</unitType></callDetails><callDetails><maintenancetype>1</maintenancetype><serialNo>2</serialNo><unitType>unit type</unitType></callDetails><callDetails><maintenancetype>2</maintenancetype><serialNo>1</serialNo><unitType>unit type</unitType></callDetails><callDetails><maintenancetype>2</maintenancetype><serialNo>2</serialNo><unitType>unit type</unitType></callDetails></callList></call>');
 
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAILS (
   IND_ID,NOTIFICATION_NO,ORDER_NO,MAINT_TYPE,SERIAL_NO,UNIT_TYPE)
  SELECT 
  call_xml.value('call/callSummary/indId[1]','CLNT(3)'),
  call_xml.value('call/callSummary/notificationNo[1]','CHAR(12)'),
  call_xml.value('call/callSummary/orderNo[1]','CHAR(12)'),
  call_xml.value('call/callSummary/callList/callDetails/maintenancetype[1]','CHAR(1)'),
  call_xml.value('call/callSummary/callList/callDetails/serialNo[1]','CHAR(1)'),
  call_xml.value('call/callSummary/callList/callDetails/unitType[1]','CHAR(20)') from call_xml.nodes('call');
  
  END;
```

I hope you understand my question, Thanx in advance.

Comment: Insert statement should include `INTO`. Try adjusting and see if error resolves.

Comment: @Parfait yeah, i included and tried..its showing again the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the xmlsequence function.   It will allow you to select a list of nodes from your XML object.  If you'd like to use pl/sql, the replace xmltype, with your variable.

```
      SELECT 
  extractValue(column_value,'callSummary/indId[1]'),
  extractValue(column_value,'callSummary/notificationNo[1]'),
  extractValue(column_value,'callSummary/orderNo[1]'),
  extractValue(column_value,'callSummary/callList/callDetails/maintenancetype[1]'),
  extractValue(column_value,'callSummary/callList/callDetails/serialNo[1]'),
  extractValue(column_value,'callSummary/callList/callDetails/unitType[1]') from table (
       xmlsequence(
         extract(
           xmltype('<call><callSummary><indId>100</indId><notificationNo>notification</notificationNo><orderNo>orderno</orderNo></callSummary><callList><callDetails><maintenancetype>1</maintenancetype><serialNo>1</serialNo><unitType>unit type</unitType></callDetails><callDetails><maintenancetype>1</maintenancetype><serialNo>2</serialNo><unitType>unit type</unitType></callDetails><callDetails><maintenancetype>2</maintenancetype><serialNo>1</serialNo><unitType>unit type</unitType></callDetails><callDetails><maintenancetype>2</maintenancetype><serialNo>2</serialNo><unitType>unit type</unitType></callDetails></callList></call>'),'/call/callSummary')));
```